# SML-Functional Programming

Tags: functional-programming, immutability, sml

I want to write a code in SML which mimics that of C++ like

```
i=i+1;
```

or

```
i++
```

In short I want to count how many times the loop(recursion) is running when the if statement is true.
Elucidating it further. My problematic code looks something like this:

```
val i = 0;
fun <function_name>() = 
   if <condition>
   then (i+1;
         <recursive_expression>)
  else expression
```

But the problem here is that the answer always is 1 no matter how many times the recursion is performed due to immutability in SML/NJ.

Any ideas will be helpful!

Comment: Can you post your whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post your whole code, i created a simple one here:

```
fun evens(int_list: int list) =
    let fun evens_helper(int_list: int list, times: int) =
    if null int_list
    then times
        else if null (tl int_list)
    then 
        if (hd int_list) mod 2 = 0
        then 1
        else 0
    else if (hd int_list) mod 2 = 0
    then 1 + evens_helper(tl int_list, times + 1)
    else evens_helper(tl int_list, times)
    in evens_helper(int_list, 0)
    end
```

To do what you need, the simplest thing to do is create a helper function inside your function, that does the exact same thing as the original function, but take one argument more (your counter). If your counter should be activated, then you call the recursive call with counter +1. If you dont want to be activated, call the recursive function using the same counter value.

If you don't get it yet, post your whole code, so i can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your if/then expression should have a similar type. Here's a quick example that you might find helpful.

```
fun how_many_evens (from,to)=
    let fun count_even (m,count) =
    if m > to then count
        else
        if m mod 2 = 0 then count_even(m+1,count+1)
        else count_even(m+1,count)

    in
        count_even (from,0)
    end
```